# Changing decimal dot to a comma

Tags: c++

The code goes like this:

> Input: Decimal number N, dot needs to be switched with notch, e.g. input: 0.36
> output: 0,36

I have been thinking about it for a couple of hours already but can't figure how to solve it. Can someone help?

Comment: Hint: you don't need to read input as number.

Comment: The slightly more interesting task is to take thousands separators into account as well. Change "1,000,000.0" to "1.000.000,0". The trivial `std::replace` solution won't work.

Comment: @MSalters it'd be a nice use case for `std::transform`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by setting the *locale* for the `cin` and `cout` streams using the [`std::imbue()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue).

The following example uses the English/US (dot) decimal separator for input and the French (comma) for output; swapping the arguments for the two `imbue` calls will reverse this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    std::cin.imbue(std::locale("en_US"));   // Set INPUT to use the DOT
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("fr_FR"));  // Set OUTPUT to use a COMMA
    double test;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> test;
    std::cout << "Number was: " << test << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The [`std::locale` section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) of the C++ Standard Template Library provides numerous options for customising (and fine-tuning) numeric input/output formats, but the techniques it offers are not trivial to master.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the number as text, and then use [`std::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string number;
    std::cin >> number;
    std::replace(number.begin(), number.end(), '.', ',');
    std::cout << number << '\n';
}
```

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    std::cin.imbue(std::locale("en_US"));   // Set INPUT to use the DOT
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("fr_FR"));  // Set OUTPUT to use a COMMA
    double test;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> test;
    std::cout << "Number was: " << test << std::endl;
    return 0;
}                                                                                       How do I do this for Croatioan language?

Comment: @Dr.Alien replace `fr_FR` with `hr_HR`.

Comment: Note that locale names are not standardized in ISO C++. `hr_HR` is a good guess.

Comment: @Dr.Alien if your question is about the locale method, you should be asking that under the other answer.